# Android Studio: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I read many posts to fix this problem. None worked for me.

**Error:**

```
Target device: lenovo-lenovo_a6000-89a70dc9
Installing APK: C:\Users\Nikhil\AndroidStudioProjects\ProfitKey\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/helix.profitkey.hotelapp
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I tried below

1. Kill and start adb
2. Invalidate and restart android studio
3. Removed adb process in the taskbar
4. Restarted the device and pc
5. Restarted studio, clean and rebuild
6. Taskbar have only one adb.exe
7. Updated the driver from device manager

Another device it is working. But previously both device worked fine for me.

```
Target device: motorola-xt1022-ZX1B33PRVP
Installing APK: C:\Users\Nikhil\AndroidStudioProjects\ProfitKey\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/helix.profitkey.hotelapp
Installing helix.profitkey.hotelapp
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/helix.profitkey.hotelapp"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/helix.profitkey.hotelapp
Success
```

**Edited:**

I tried with two lenovo A6000. One is working and another is not working. Then, Moto is working and samsung galaxy is not working. Whenever I am killing and starting the adb. The task manager creating two adb first and after few seconds one was hiding. Was this a problem? But still some devices working fine.

adb starts automatically after killing by command or from the task manager if android studio is opened.

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled USB debugging in the device where it is not working?

Comment: @ Devanshu Dwivedi Thanks.  Yes I enabled USB debugging.

Comment: When I suddenly get this kind of problem, I usually have to remove manually leftover app data from the device and then it works

Comment: Did you try to delete the trusted devices? may be you didn't accept the certificate popup the first time.

Comment: @Filippo Bottonelli, I uninstalled the app and tried. Same error coming. I didn't delete the trusted device. I gave always trust this device when that popup came "cgarrido"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Now working for all the devices. Just I uninstalled the driver of mobile in PC and changed the port to connect with that device. I think some problem with the port in my PC. After long research it fixed by a small thing. It might be helpful to someone.

Comment: Ohh, yes that was just  port problem.It was front comp USB slot. May be it has some wave resistance/inductivity as its long leds aren't wrapped by foil.

Answer (score 5):

I also faced same problem,this was a just port problem,I was using computer front USB port ,just use computer back USB port and problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

Restarting `adb.exe` worked for me. (For windows, Just Go to taskManager and kills the `adb.exe` process and re-deploy)

Answer (score 2):

I also faced same problem, just change computer USB port and problem solved.  or use genymotion emulator

Answer (score 0):

I closed my virtual devices, opened windows task manager, and killed all adb.exe tasks -- there was one constant one and another that would appear then disappear. Aftwerwards, i started my virtual device and everything worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that no other program is trying to take control of the ADB. You can check this by opening task manager, right clicking on any of the adb.exe, and opening the file location. Turns out that my HTC sync manager had it's own ADB and wanted to run it all the time. I uninstalled the program and haven't had issues since.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to change the USB debugging cable.