# Connected device [OFFLINE] - Session 'app': Error Installing APKs - existing connection was forcibly closed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When I trying to:

> RUN > Select Deployment target > Select my Real Android device.

I after build my device disconnect automatically and Device status [OFFLINE]

**EVENT LOG HERE:**

```
2:40 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

2:41 PM Gradle build finished with 1 warnings(s) in 7s 577ms

2:41 PM An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
                java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
                at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
                at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
                at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
                at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
                at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
                at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:471)
                at com.android.ddmlib.SplitApkInstaller.uploadApk(SplitApkInstaller.java:152)
                at com.android.ddmlib.SplitApkInstaller.install(SplitApkInstaller.java:78)
                at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackages(Device.java:904)
                at com.android.tools.idea.run.tasks.SplitApkDeployTask$SplitApkInstaller.installApp(SplitApkDeployTask.java:117)
                at com.android.tools.idea.run.RetryingInstaller.install(RetryingInstaller.java:86)
                at com.android.tools.idea.run.tasks.SplitApkDeployTask.perform(... (show balloon)

2:41 PM Session 'app': Error Installing APKs
```

And also sometime I found event log like this in Android Studio 2.3:

```
2:27 PM IllegalStateException
                Android Studio could not interpret the results of the Gradle build correctly.
                You may be able to recover from this issue by pressing 'Run' or 'Debug' again.
                Please file a bug at b.android.com including this message and your idea.log (Help | Show Log in ..).

    Session 'app': Error Launching activity .
```

**Already Tried.**

- Disable Instant Run feature from settings.
- Perform a clean build and run again.
- Terminal window = start and stop adb server using this command "adb kill-server" and "adb start-server".
- Enable and Disable USB Debugging.
  -

[image]

**Note:** If I restart my device and Windows PC then it works but I can't restart every time so any one have better solutions for 'app': Error Installing APKs issues.

Comment: invalidate caches and restart.

Comment: Please go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36029809/android-studio-java-io-ioexception-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed

Comment: @DkThakur I tried this but not working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this - [ADB Android Device Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081263/adb-android-device-unauthorized).

This will work for you. if not then let me inform.

Comment: I also tried command "adb kill-server" and "adb start-server" - If you read my que's Already Tried.  Thanks.