# Android Studio app install on phone failed

Tags: android, apk

My device is Huawei Honor.
I am getting this error when i try to install apk :

**java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Error while Installing APK**

Android Studio recognizes my device but when I try to run the device gets offline.
I tried other methods from other similar question but nothing worked.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36029809/android-studio-java-io-ioexception-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36029809/android-studio-java-io-ioexception-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed)

Comment: I tried the mentioned methods  , but it didn't worked

Comment: Does it work on other devices?